# Calculating new bounds after rotating a square

Tags: ios, objective-c, trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate the size of a bounding box after rotating a square. I've attached an image that hopefully describes what I'm looking to do.

[image]

After rotating by x degrees, the bounds becomes bigger. Is there a way to calculate this new size, given the angle and the dimensions of the original square? Thank you.

Comment: What is the point that you rotate your square around? (I'm sorry if it's unclear what I'm saying). Are you rotating it around it's center? I guess, this is a question for [Math.StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/). P.S. If you're interested only in size of the new bounding rectangle, not it's position, than the point of rotation doesn't matter, I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: You can use trig to get the new dimensions. If you know the original width, you can calculate the new width as the sum of the adjacent and opposite sides of the white triangle that is formed in your second image. `newWidth = width*cos(angle) + width*sin(angle)`

Comment: If that square is a UIImageView and it's rotated by changing the `transform` property of the view, then the bounding box is the `frame` property of the view.  In fact, what you've drawn there is pretty much the definition of the `frame` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved through 2 applications of Pythag.

Each side of your larger square is split into two by a corner of your small blue square. Lets call the larger of these 2 sections length a, the smaller length b (although if x > 45 degrees then b will be larger), with side length l for the blue square and L as length of the black square.

We can calculate the first as: Cos(x) = a/l.
And the 2nd as Sin(x) = b/l

Thus we have L = (Sin(x)+Cos(x))*l.

Edit: Area is of course side length squared in both cases.

Comment: assuming `x` is an angle (in radians), we have `L = (|sin(x)| + |cos(x)|)*l`

Answer (score 1):

This works only if you have the co-ordinates. If you can get the co-ordinates of the four vertices, it would be so easy.. Lets assume the point at the top left corner of the bound be `A`. And the top two vertices of the square be sq_a and sq_b. The value of the vertex `A` would be `(sq_a.x,sq_b.y)`. Then by symmetry , all the small four triangles formed between the bound and the square will be of the same area. Calculate the area of the triangle formed between `A`,`sq_a` and `sq_b` (which should be easy .. `1/2 * breadth * height`). Multiply by 4 and the you will get the total area. Sorry couldnt post detailed pics.